# keyerror after removing nans in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am reading a file with `pd.read_csv` and removing all the values that are `-1`. Here's the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
catalog = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\s+', names=columns, skiprows=1)

a = cataog['A']
b = cataog['B']
c = cataog['C']
d = cataog['D']

print len(b) # answer is 700

# remove rows that are -1 in column b
idx = np.where(b != -1)[0]
a = a[idx]
b = b[idx]
c = c[idx]
d = d[idx]

print len(b) # answer is 612
```

So I am assuming that I have successfully managed to remove all the rows where the value in column b is -1.

In order to test this, I am doing the following naive way:

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    print i, a[i], b[i]
```

It prints out the values until it reaches a row which was supposedly filtered out. But now it gives a `KeyError`.

Comment: Could you check `len(a)`, in particular `len(a) == len(b)`?

Comment: yes they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
catalog = catalog[catalog['B'] != -1]

a = cataog['A']
b = cataog['B']
c = cataog['C']
d = cataog['D']
```

It is expected you get `KeyError`, because index values not match, because filtering.

One possible solution is convert `Series` to `list`s:

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    print i, list(a)[i], list(b)[i]
```

**Sample**:

```
catalog = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[-1,5,4,5,-1,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0]})

print (catalog)
   A  B  C  D
0  a -1  7  1
1  b  5  8  3
2  c  4  9  5
3  d  5  4  7
4  e -1  2  1

#filtered DataFrame have no index 0, 4
catalog = catalog[catalog['B'] != -1]
print (catalog)
   A  B  C  D
1  b  5  8  3
2  c  4  9  5
3  d  5  4  7
5  f  4  3  0
```

---

```
a = catalog['A']
b = catalog['B']
c = catalog['C']
d = catalog['D']

print (b)
1    5
2    4
3    5
5    4
Name: B, dtype: int64

#a[i] in first loop want match index value 0 (a[0]) what does not exist, so KeyError,
#same problem for b[0]
for i in range(len(b)):
    print (i, a[i], b[i])
```

> KeyError: 0

---

```
#convert Series to list, so list(a)[0] return first value of list - there is no Series index
for i in range(len(b)):
    print (i, list(a)[i], list(b)[i])
0 b 5
1 c 4
2 d 5
3 f 4
```

Another solution should be create default index `0,1,...` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
catalog = catalog[catalog['B'] != -1].reset_index(drop=True)    
print (catalog)
   A  B  C  D
0  b  5  8  3
1  c  4  9  5
2  d  5  4  7
3  f  4  3  0

a = catalog['A']
b = catalog['B']
c = catalog['C']
d = catalog['D']

#default index values match a[0] and a[b]
for i in range(len(b)):
    print (i, a[i], b[i])

0 b 5
1 c 4
2 d 5
3 f 4
```

Comment: .reset_index(drop=True) is a saviour! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you filter out indices, then

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    print i, a[i], b[i]
```

will attempt to access erased indices. Instead, you can use the following:

```
for i, ae, be in zip(a.index, a.values, b.values):
    print(i, ae, be)
```